# How do I implement structural Equals for an F# class?

Tags: f#, equality

In C# I would implement `Equals` for a class with structural equality like this:

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (this == obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var other = obj as MyType;
    if (other != null)
    {
        return someField == other.someField && 
            someOtherField == other.someOtherField;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In F# we have records for this, but if we want to use inheritance a `type` must be implemented.

What is the equivalent `Equals` implementation in F#?

Comment: just override equals - can be done in F#?

Comment: Yes, but what would the body of the override look like?

Comment: F# records implicitly implement `IStructuralEquatable` and override `Object.Equals` unless overriden by the definition.

Comment: much the same as C#?

Comment: I would like to see an example implementation to help me learn the language. Also a direct translation may not be the best way to do it in F#. e.g. is `null` treated differently?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you just need to override `Equals`. The compiler will also tell you that it is a good idea to override `GetHashCode`.

One neat trick is that you can just take all the relevant fields of your class, create tuples with them and then compare the tuples (or take hash code of the tuple). This makes the implementation much easier than if you were doing this by hand:

```
type Person(name:string, age:int) =
  member x.Name = name
  member x.Age = age
  override x.GetHashCode() =
    hash (name, age)
  override x.Equals(b) =
    match b with
    | :? Person as p -> (name, age) = (p.Name, p.Age)
    | _ -> false

Person("Joe", 42) = Person("Joe", 42)
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasPetricek; that trick with tuples is exactly the kind of thing a C# developer doing a direct translation would not consider.

Comment: @sdgfsdh : That's presumptuous – C# has tuples too. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn But imagine the type annotations!

Comment: @sdgfsdh: For a local variable you shouldn't need any type annotation, just use `Tuple.Create`'s type inference. `return Tuple.Create(this.name, this.age) == Tuple.Create(other.Name, other.Age)`

Comment: @sdgfsdh In C# you can use anonymous types: `new { field1, field2 }` In both F# and C# you need to pay attention to how these fields are compared then though...

Comment: @TomasPetricek You are better off requiring strict types equality. Just checking `is a` relationship is not enough unless class is sealed.